# Connect All Siblings in Binary Tree Using Pointers

Tags: pointers, binary-tree, siblings

[image: Correct Outcome]

Problem: https://www.educative.io/m/connect-all-siblings

I'm attempting to connect all sibling nodes by creating a dummy node and set it's next to the node that we're currently visiting by using a next pointer, but after executing the code:

```
    public static void populate_sibling_pointers(BinaryTreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return;
        Queue<BinaryTreeNode> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.offer(root);

        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            int size = q.size();
            BinaryTreeNode dummy = new BinaryTreeNode(0);
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                BinaryTreeNode cur = q.poll();
                dummy.next = cur;
                dummy = dummy.next;
                if(cur.left!=null){
                    q.offer(cur.left);
                }
                if(cur.right!=null){
                    q.offer(cur.right);
                }            
            }
        }
    }
```

I still failed to pass some test but I'm not sure what I did wrong here.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- You should create a `new` dummy node only *once*. By creating a new one at every iteration of the `while` loop, you break the chain of `next` references. So the creation of that node should happen *before* the `while` loop.
- The last node in the `next` chain should have its `next` set to `null`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
class connectSiblings{
    public static void populate_sibling_pointers(BinaryTreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return;
        Queue<BinaryTreeNode> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.offer(root);

        BinaryTreeNode dummy = new BinaryTreeNode(0);
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            int size = q.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                BinaryTreeNode cur = q.poll();
                dummy.next = cur;
                dummy = dummy.next;
                if(cur.left!=null){
                    q.offer(cur.left);
                }
                if(cur.right!=null){
                    q.offer(cur.right);
                }            
            }
        }
        dummy.next = null;
    }
}
```

You can further optimise this code by replacing the use of the `LinkedList` with the actual linked list you are building with the `next` references: when a layer of the tree has been correctly wired with `next` references, you can iterate that section of that linked list to find and wire the nodes of the next layer, which then can serve as linked list for the next layer, ...etc.